Swiper JS - Problem with centeredSlides: true, slidesPerView: "auto", loop: true
I'm having a problem with my slider, is not completely centered, one of the slides is on the other side and the slider does not look centered, this is my code example. I appreciated your help :).
[https://codepen.io/danbandera/pen/PogQbyX](https://codepen.io/danbandera/pen/PogQbyX)
I've tried with many slider libraries and Swiper JS works the best for my needs.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
